# ASP.NET updatepanel not refreshing the dropdownlist controls

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I have recently added a updatepanel in my aspx page. My controls are inside a HTML table, labels, dropdownlist etc. And i want the dropdown lists to refresh only.. but no hope at all.. any help..

The sample code is below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table id="Table5" height="50" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="200" border="1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="110" height="21">
                                            <p align="left">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblDomain" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="51px">Domain</asp:Label></p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="110" height="21">
                                            <p align="left">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblSystem" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="51px">System</asp:Label></p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 86px" nowrap width="86" height="21">
                                            <p align="left">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblVendor" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="88px">Select Vendor</asp:Label></p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRegion" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="77px">Select Region</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblNode" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="80px">Select Node</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRouteType" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="91px"
                                                Visible="False">Select Route Type</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRoute" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="80px">Select Route</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblUtil" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="80px">Enter Utilization &gt; than</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td width="51">

                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDomain" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="89px"
                                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                                <asp:ListItem>National</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>International</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>[All]</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </td>
                                        <td width="51">

                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSystem" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="55px"
                                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                                <asp:ListItem>NNN</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>III</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>TTT</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </td>
                                        <td width="50">

                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVendor" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="91px"
                                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="80px"
                                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNode" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="80px"
                                                AutoPostBack="True">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRouteType" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="80px"
                                                Visible="False">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRoute" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Width="80px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbUtil" runat="server" CssClass="reportOption" Height="20px" Width="51px">0.0</asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And yes the script manager is there too..

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="AjaxScriptManagerforDDL" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine, you have placed your dropdowns in update panel, and all your dropdowns are Autopostback=true.

Clearly when you select any value from dropdownlist, page should not get refreshed. Thats what is happening with this code.

I created a aspx page, added a script manager, and then added your code, its working fine.

Comment: Hi.. this is really strange. Ok in my project there are some ascx pages also which are added in the beginning of the aspx page. Basically it contains some header/ footer. Does it have anything to do with it.